# Highcharts: misaligned date on multiple axis

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a Stockchart graph using two Y and two X axis. When I set `selected` on the `rangeSelector` to something high, it works fine. But if it needs to cut out some of the months the two x axis become misaligned. The upper two line graphs seem to begin outside of the graph.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gn393/5/ (with `selected` set high, aligned)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gn393/6/ (with `selected` set low, misaligned)

The line graph on the lower x axis does not change when zooming in the above examples. I use `afterSetExtremes` for that. But the issue is still reproducible in the above Fiddles.

```
yAxis: [{
    height: 420,
    lineWidth: 2,
}, {
    top: 500,
    height: 210,
    lineWidth: 2,
}],
xAxis: [{
    type: 'datetime',
    opposite: true,
    offset: -700,
},{
    type: 'datetime',

    offset: -200,
}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case when you have two xAxis, you need to render button and call setExtremes function on both actions. Because buttons works only for first xAxis. Second solution is using afterSetExtremes and call setExtremes on second xAxis.

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/gn393/8/

```
xAxis: [{
                    type: 'datetime',
                    opposite: true,
                    offset: -700,
                    events:{
                        afterSetExtremes:function(){
                            var min = this.min,
                                max = this.max,
                                chart = this.chart;

                            chart.xAxis[1].setExtremes(min,max);

                        }
                    },
                },{
                    type: 'datetime',

                    offset: -200,
                }],
```

Comment: But in neither of the two Fiddles I am using the `setExtremes` function. And despite that I am able to reproduce the same behavior.

Comment: In your fiddle, why is the xAxis off by one month? And why are the two yAxis displayed on different locations?

Comment: @dan-klasson two yAxis are on different posigiton becasue you have top parameter in second one.

Comment: But the `top` is necessary to place the second `yAxis` below the first. How can I align them and the `xAxis` that is off by one month?

Comment: About aligning you mean labels align? Referring to offset, you can set [timezoneOffset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.timezoneOffset) or [useUTC](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC) as false

Comment: You're right. I need labels: {x: 10,},. The other issue is unrelated and probably due to the data. I unsuccesfully tried fiddling around with `timezoneOffset` and `useUTC`. Going to start another SO question regarding that

Comment: The other issue is related to the timestamp being the last day of the month.